# Redux-Form, how to use a Ref with a renderField?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I'm trying to add a ref attribute to one of my redux-form fields.. Here's the code:

```
let renderField = ({input, label, placeholder, type, meta: {submitFailed, touched, error, pristine}}) =>

  <div className={classNames("form-group", {
    "has-danger": (submitFailed && error) || (!pristine && touched && error),
    "has-success": !pristine && touched && !error
  })}>
    <textarea {...input} type={type} placeholder={placeholder} className={touched ? (error ? "form-control form-control-danger" : "form-control form-control-success") : "form-control"} />
  </div>
```

..... within the render func

```
      <Field
        name="message"
        type="textarea"
        component={renderField}
        placeholder="Enter your message..."
        validate={[required]}
        ref="message"
        withRef={true}
      />
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs (See ref "renderedComponent" in renderField created by ConnectedField). Attempts to access this ref will fail
```

How can I get a ref added to my redux-form Field?

Comment: Refs and Redux-bound views don't work well together. You may have mysterious problems later on. I think you'll be better off passing an `onChange` callback, or the like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create class instead of function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class RenderField extends Component {
  render() {...}
}
```

Comment: @AnApprentice it available as this.props.input, this.props.label, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you need to create a stateful component. You can do this by extending [React.Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html). See [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class) from the docs on how to convert an existing functional component.